# How do wrap a Card around SliverList?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a Sliver List and I want to encapsulate it in a card. This is my code for the Sliver List:

```
  Widget hello() {
    return SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 0.0,
        bottom: 100.0,
      ),
      sliver: SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 4,
                bottom: 4,
                left: 8,
                right: 8,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    color: Color(0xff9a9a9a),
                    height: 0.5,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Image.network('http://cdn.akc.org/content/hero/cute_puppies_hero.jpg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Hello',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      'This is a puppy',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
          childCount: 8,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is how I've called it :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
 backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 248, 251, 1),
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomScrollView(
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  hello(),
                 ..other widgets are called here..
                ],
              ),  
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve with my SliverList which I am want to display inside a card :
[image]

When I try to wrap the SliverList with a Card I get a RenderFlex error and it doesnt accecpt the Card as a child.

Comment: Do you want to put the whole list inside a card?

Comment: Yes I want to wrap the whole list in a card

Comment: You can wrap `CustomScrollView` with a card. But you can't directly wrap `SliverList` if you are using `CustomScrollView`.

Comment: But I need to call other widgets too in my CustomScrollView. These widgets do not need to be a part of my card.

Comment: will that widget scroll with the list? So will they be at the end of the `CustomScrollView`?

Comment: In CustomScrollView all  `Widget`s in  `slivers` must produce `RenderSliver` objects.
You can't pass anything that does not. I would recommend to try simplier scebario with ListView in Scaffold body

Comment: yeah the widgets need to scroll with the page. The card with the list view is between the widgets.

Comment: I don't think if you can achieve it directly. So you can wrap `CustomScrollView` with card and wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView` and add more contents along with `CustomScrollView`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those who's still looking for the answer: you can use SliverStack widget from the wonderful package [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliver_tools/sliver_tools.dart';

CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverStack(
      insetOnOverlap: false,
      children: [
        SliverPositioned.fill(child: Card()),
        SliverList(...),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wrap SliverList or SliverList.builder with Widgets . If you want Card properties in your list you can do something like this:

```
CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                 child: Card(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: xyz.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {}
                    ),     
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
```